# Is there a way to fix an unaligned plus sign in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use Tikz to transform MATLAB plots in Latex but I use exponential notation for numbers in these plots. However the output features a "plus" sign that is a bit off.

[image: offset plus sign]

Is there a way to fix this ?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node{6.2e+10};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, the position of the plus sign is not "off"; it is designed that way so that the vertical center of the plus lies at the same height as a minus sign (the "math axis").  You are probably familiar with the convention often used when including a plus sign in text (or by other software).  I don't have a tex system available to test, but I believe that the "typewriter" plus has the alignment you want.  If that is the case, and the weight of that plus looks okay to you, you might try this definition: `\newcommand{\plus}{\texttt{\char`\+}}` and enter your node as `\node{6.2e\plus 10}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\sisetup{
  output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
  exponent-product={},
  retain-explicit-plus
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node{\num{6.2e+10}};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tried it but the result seems to be the same than with the code in the question. (tested on overleaf)